# Composer could not fetch github

Tags: php, github, composer-php

Today, I try to do Laravel install by running `composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.1.* myproject --prefer-dist` and I get this error:

```
Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/laravel/zipball/716e65268ae123e5bd73e505acf9695c678aff88, please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+MyPC+2016-02-19+0343 to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "C:/Users/MyPC/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
```

Why am I unable to fetch from GitHub? This is the first time I am facing this after years of using. Is there any policy change by GitHub?

Comment: composer create-project laravel/laravel 5.1 myproject --prefer-dist

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/

Comment: "please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This policy has been active at Github a long time regrettably. It is documented [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/) and you can see your current status at https://api.github.com/rate_limit in the `core` section.

Also see https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting:

> For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows you to make up to 60 requests per hour. Unauthenticated requests are associated with your IP address, and not the user making requests.

There is nothing Composer can do to circumvent that, hence why it throws the verbose error:

> Create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit

You can do this at https://github.com/settings/tokens, and it needs to be done only once per installation as Composer remembers the token for subsequent requests.

Comment: Is a read:packages scope enough or are there other grants that should be authorized ?

Comment: This is the updated link to reference the rate limit for unauthenticated requests: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#rate-limits-for-requests-from-personal-accounts

Answer (score 29):

**2022 Update for Composer 2.x**

I tried the other solutions listed here and they didn't work for me. Inspecting the verbose output of `composer update` I found that you can set the `github.accesstoken` configuration option using `git` and Composer will use that.

1. Create a [GitHub Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and copy the token to your clipboard
2. Run `git config --global github.accesstoken <token>`, replacing `<token>` with the token from above.

You can remove the `--global` option if you want to set the token specifically for your current project.

Comment: Ah this worked for me and should be the accepted answer for Composer v2 :)

Comment: Thank you - do you know what minimal permissions the token needs?

Comment: this worked, and read:packages was the only permission needed

Comment: thanks. so many suggestion, only this works.

Comment: Thank you, that one works like charm for me.

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer of Niels is correct. To use the generated token in composer use the command:

```
composer config -g github-oauth.github.com YOUR_TOKEN
```

Comment: just create new token from this link: https://github.com/settings/tokens then use above command to set token. done.