# curl error 6 while downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit: Could not resolve host: api.github.com CakePHP4

Tags: docker, composer-php, cakephp-4.x

I'm very new to docker and I keep getting this error from a couple of days ago and it didn't happen before. Looks like I exceeded the limit of api access or something.

````
```
OS: WSL(Ubuntu22.04)
PHP: PHP 8.1.16
Composer: 2.5.4
Docker: Docker version 23.0.1
Docker Compose: v2.16.0
```
````

1. Pulled my GitHub project on my WSL2 Ubuntu22.04
2. Ran `docker compose up -d --build` to create images and containers

- Here is my docker file for php

  ```
  FROM php:8.1-apache

  # Composer version and Hash
  ARG composer_ver=2.5.4
  ARG composer_hash=91ce6cbf9463eae86ae9d5c21d42faa601a519f3fbb2b623a55ee24678079bd3
  # Composer
  ARG composer_path=/usr/local/bin/composer

  RUN apt-get update \
    && php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/download/$composer_ver/composer.phar', '$composer_path');" \
    && chmod 755 $composer_path \
    && php -r "if (hash_file('sha256', '$composer_path') !== '$composer_hash') { \
            echo '!!! Failed to install Composer !!!'; \
            unlink('$composer_path'); \
        } \
        echo PHP_EOL;" \
    && apt-get install -y unzip \
    && apt-get install -y libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && a2enmod rewrite
  ```

3. Entered the container and ran `composer install`
4. Got this kind of errors ↓

   ```
   Failed to download dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer from dist: curl error 6 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/PHPCSStandards/composer-installer/zipball/4be43904336affa5c2f70744a348312336afd0da: Could not resolve host: api.github.com
       Now trying to download from source
   ```
5. After that I ran `composer diag` to check composer info and found this ↓

   ```
   Checking composer.json: OK
   Checking platform settings: OK
   Checking git settings: No git process found
   Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
   Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
   Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
   [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 6 while downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit: Could not resolve host: api.github.com
   Checking disk free space: OK
   Checking pubkeys:
   Tags Public Key Fingerprint: XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX
   Dev Public Key Fingerprint: XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX
   OK
   Checking composer version: OK
   Composer version: 2.5.4
   PHP version: 8.1.16
   PHP binary path: /usr/local/bin/php
   OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
   cURL version: 7.74.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1n
   zip: extension not loaded, unzip present, 7-Zip not available
   ```
6. I googled this error and found this article [Composer could not fetch github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496848/composer-could-not-fetch-github) but the error message wasn't the same but I created Personal Access Token and ran `composer config -g github-oauth.github.com TOKEN` in the container and tried 4. and 5. again but both failed.

I'm still looking at multiple websites for answers but none of them worked.
If my English confuses you, I have to apologize it's not my first language.

Any help would be appreciate! Thank you!

Comment: "Could not resolve host: api.github.com", seems that you have some networking or DNS issue?

Comment: It was actually DNS issue. I changed the nameserver in `resolve.conf` to 8.8.8.8. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

So it was DNS error.

1. Created the file in wsl `/etc/wsl.conf`
2. Inside that `wsl.conf`, I added

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

3. shutdown wsl and entered it back
4. change the nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` to `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

This worked for me.